# How to attach token to git command?

Tags: git, github

I have a private repo in github.

I can't run git command to show all the tags because I'm not authorize: `git ls-remote -t https://github.com/.../..git`.

Is there a way to add a token or access key to this command that allow me to execute this command?

something like: `git ls-remote -t https://github.com/../...git -token blabla`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow those steps:

1. Go to your [profile settings in Github](https://github.com/settings/profile).
2. In "developer settings" create a key.
3. use the key in the url: `git ls-remote -t https://youuser:accesskey@github.com/../...git`

**This key is particularly sensitive.**

hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

If you can shift to using `ssh` (git@github.com... URLs) instead of `https`, your keypair will automatically take care of auth without having to manually enter passwords.

Comment: You can. I tried `git ls-remote -t git@github.com:nibrahim/Hyde.git` and it worked since I have already provided credentials.

Comment: but how I'm pass the ssh key? I want to this command to work anywhere with the correct token.

Comment: Do I need to set the credentials in Jenkins machine? this is a problem for others github repos.

Comment: You'll need a keypair for the jenkins machine and then add the public key for that machine to all the repos.